# How can I get an Excel cell given column and row numbers in Applescript?

Tags: excel, applescript

All the applescript examples for getting a cell in Excel I can find use `A1` notation, like this:

```
set c to range 'A1'
```

I would like to do that with the column and row number instead - like this

```
set c to range 1, 23
```

or something similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example to use cell A23:

```
set a to value of cell 23 of column 1
```

Offsets are a little odd too, and may come in handy - active cell examples:

```
set b to value of (get offset active cell column offset 4)
set c to value of (get offset active cell column offset 4 row offset 2)
```

So you can also do this, which would give you the value of E5:

```
set d to value of (get offset cell "A1" column offset 4 row offset 4)
```